# How can I use REST to copy an object in Documentum 7.x

Tags: java, documentum, spring-rest

I am looking to create a physical copy of a sub type of dm_document using the DCTM REST API.  I am pretty new to the DCTM world, especially when it comes to the REST API.

The use case that I have is when a certain action happens, I need to clone the document (meta & content) and alter 1 or 2 pieces of meta and save that new document back the repository.

I have reviewed all the examples located here: https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-34346 however, I am unable to figure out how to retrieve the document & content using this example (Spring Rest) having just the r_object_id.  I have used this example to create content, therefore if I could just download the content & meta to my application, I could do the rest.  However no matter what I try - I can't seem to get the data using the r_object_id.

If anyone could provide a pointer, it would help me out a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use the dfc.jar instead of the rest api? You can get the content and the object with it.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you get the object information, and it's content. I really wanted to know how to do these things too so i tried hard and finally got it fully working.

For making the request you will need to use xmlconfigeditor.jar from documentum. Other base64 encodings are not working...

I used java-json.jar for easy use of the jsons. It is not a "must" have. But it will help you a lot. Otherwise you will need to read the json string yourself.

I used @Eddie 's answer from [Java: Reading a pdf file from URL into Byte array/ByteBuffer in an applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637100/java-reading-a-pdf-file-from-url-into-byte-array-bytebuffer-in-an-applet) to get the file from url as byte array.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String repository_name = "";
    String r_object_id = "";

    JSONObject theObject = makeRequest("http://localhost:8000/dctm-rest/repositories/"
            + repository_name + "/objects/" + r_object_id);

    if (theObject != null) {

        // you have all information about the object now
        // you can access the attributes of the object by
        // theObject.getJSONObject("properties") then like
        // .getString("object_name")

        JSONObject contentJSON = makeRequest("http://localhost:8000/dctm-rest/repositories/"
                + repository_name
                + "/objects/"
                + r_object_id
                + "/contents/content");

        JSONArray js = contentJSON.getJSONArray("links");
        for (int i = 0; i < js.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = js.getJSONObject(i);
            if (jo.has("title") && "ACS".equals(jo.getString("title"))) {

                // here is your byte array
                byte[] bytes = getAsByteArray(new URL(jo.getString("href")))
                        .array();

            }
        }
    }

}

public static JSONObject makeRequest(String url) {

    JSONObject json = null;

    String username = "";
    String password = "";

    String strResponse = "";

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    BufferedReader rd = null;
    CloseableHttpResponse cls = null;

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setSocketTimeout(120 * 1000).setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(30 * 1000).build();

    request.setConfig(config);

    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.emc.documentum+json");

    request.addHeader(
            "Authorization",
            "Basic "
                    + com.documentum.xmlconfig.util.Base64.encode(username
                            + ":" + password));

    try {

        cls = httpClient.execute(request);

        HttpEntity entity = cls.getEntity();

        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while (line != null) {
            line = rd.readLine();
            strResponse += line;
        }

        strResponse = strResponse.trim().replace("\n", "");

        String statusline = cls.getStatusLine().toString();
        if (!statusline.contains("200") && !statusline.contains("201")) {

            System.out.println(strResponse);

        } else {

            json = new JSONObject(strResponse);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;

}

public static ByteBuffer getAsByteArray(URL url) throws IOException {
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    // Since you get a URLConnection, use it to get the InputStream
    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    // Now that the InputStream is open, get the content length
    int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();

    // To avoid having to resize the array over and over and over as
    // bytes are written to the array, provide an accurate estimate of
    // the ultimate size of the byte array
    ByteArrayOutputStream tmpOut;
    if (contentLength != -1) {
        tmpOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream(contentLength);
    } else {
        tmpOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream(16384); // Pick some appropriate
                                                    // size
    }

    byte[] buf = new byte[512];
    while (true) {
        int len = in.read(buf);
        if (len == -1) {
            break;
        }
        tmpOut.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    tmpOut.close(); // No effect, but good to do anyway to keep the metaphor
                    // alive

    byte[] array = tmpOut.toByteArray();

    // Lines below used to test if file is corrupt
    // FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\abc.pdf");
    // fos.write(array);
    // fos.close();

    return ByteBuffer.wrap(array);
}
```

}

Comment: I appreciate your code example, and will attempt to integrate it into my code base and will respond with how it goes.

Comment: I haven't got to it yet unfortunately. Been hit with some production issues. I am going to need to figure out how to do this based on your code with the Spring REST client. So it'll take me a bit.

Comment: Ok. Good luck. I hope you can solve it, feel free to ask if there are confusing parts in my code